# Unity3d - ios duplicate method found with fmod

Tags: ios, duplicates, unity-game-engine, static-libraries, native

I am using an fmod plugin for Unity3D. Compiling to Windows and OSX is fine because I can dynamically load the DLL/dylib.
The problem comes when I compile for iOS. I use

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
```

Because iOS requires statically linked libraries. When I compile though I get a

```
SystemException: Duplicate native method found : FMOD_System_CreateSound. Please check your source carefully.
```

I am quite sure I don't duplicate the symbol. I think this might be due to the fact that Unity imports FMODs itself and that the two might be colliding... But if this is the case, I am surprised that FMOD_System_CreateSound is the first one to get caught. Is there a way around this? thx!

As always, I will be happy to provide any additional details!

Here is a sample project that will cause the error:
[Sample Unity Project with FMod](http://speedy.sh/V9WGw/FMOD-Unity-Demo.zip)

EDIT:
The conflict was caused by iOS not allowing functions to have the same name even though they don't have the same signature. After removing the same-named functions (thus removing some FMOD features that I didn't need), I can compile to iOS, but as expected, I still get an error when Initializing because FMOD is already initialized by Unity.

Comment: i had the same problem, with the Reachability Code from Apple because unity actually did already implement it.
did you try using FMOD over Unity API? or is there a feature missing from FMOD that you need? i've read that unity exposed some features of FMOD.

Comment: did you try this? http://www.squaretangle.com/FMODUnity.html

Comment: FMOD over Unity API will not allow me to stream data from outside the iOS sandbox. I need the full FMOD API. The square tangle plugin does not solve the issue. It is simply using the .cs from the Windows API and including them in the Unity project. Plus, it says on that page you linked that it does not work on iOS ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to your edit and after looking at the sample, it is true that you cannot have two methods of the same name as the compiler will not recognize which to link to.

The easy fix is to obviously name them differently.

As for the initialization, if you can access the FMOD that Unity 3D already created, then you don't have to reinitialize it.

I assume that a pointer to that object will be sufficient to remove the duplicate initialization. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I started looking into this solution today, trying to use C#'s builtin reflection to get a reference to the system object. Couldn't quite find it though... I did try and initialize FMOD in the main.mm before anything Unity happens and indeed Unity isn't happy that FMOD is initialized! I will keep looking into this. I also saw that you can create a SoundCLip in unity in pretty much the same way as a stream in fmod, this might be OK

Answer (score 2):

**Unity3d already has a limited version of FMOD that is bundled with it**, which is causing the conflict you are seeing. Unfortunately, **it doesn't seem possible to disable** it at this time, so that you can use the full version of FMOD

Comment: This man was able to disable FMOD in Unity: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/124373-Working-FMOD-plugin-for-iOS-who-is-interested

Comment: The conflict was caused by iOS not allowing functions to have the same name even though they don't have the same signature. After removing the same-named functions (thus removing some FMOD features that I didn't need), I can compile to iOS, but as expected, I still get an error when Initializing because FMOD is already initialized by Unity.